# I want to repeat a function using for loop but the for loop does nothing

Tags: javascript

I'm coding a game using `HTML`,`CSS` and `JavaScript`. And I've create a function that countdown a p-tag in the HTML code but it subtract just one number every time the function executed, so i need to execute this function a lot of time and when the countdown rich zero the game finish.

I've tried to put a for loop in but the for loop does nothing.

My `JavaScript` function :

```
function time() {
    for (i=0;i<30;i++) {
        var enem = document.getElementById("enem");
        var timer = document.getElementById("timer1").innerHTML;
        var timer = parseInt(timer);
        var actime = timer - 1;
        sleep(1000).then(() => {
        timer = document.getElementById("timer1").innerHTML = actime;
        if (timer===0) {
            enem.parentNode.removeChild(enem);
            window.location.href = ('success.html');
        }
        })
        }
}
```

I except the result of time() function will change the p-tag every 1 second 30 time, but it change just one time.

Comment: can you use an async function or not?

Comment: I’m a beginner, can you explain please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Javascript's setInterval function for it.

```js
(function(){
var n = 30;
var tm = setInterval(countDown,1000);
var enem = document.getElementById("enem");
var timer = document.getElementById("timer1");
function countDown(){
   n--;
   if(n == 0){
      clearInterval(tm);
      enem.parentNode.removeChild(enem);
      window.location.href = ('success.html');
   }
   timer.innerHTML = n;
}})();
```

```html
<p id="enem"></p>
<p id="timer1"></p>
```

Comment: It works but when it reach 1 the countdown stop counting.

Answer (score 0):

You’re looking for `setInterval()`, which is the way Javascript perform a certain action every specific period of time.

The code you posted won’t work because of the non-blocking nature of Javascript, it will schedule the sleep function call, and move along with the next loop.

Comment: Thank you, so should i read more about setInterval() function ?

Comment: Yes, it should take you few minutes to figure out it’s usage and learn it’s syntax. Then, it should replace the for-loop, with no need to sleep anymore. Execuse me of not typing the code, but I’m on my phone. Let me how it works.